# Minimize the oracle DB queries

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a java application, where am performing the following query to fetch the data

```
SELECT prod.product_id,
       prod.product_name,
       product.stock,
       st.status_code,
       st.status_desc,
       usr1.user_nameas AS soldby,
       usr2.user_nameas soldto
  FROM product prod
  JOIN status ON prod.status_code = st.status_code
  LEFT JOIN user usr1 ON prod.agent_id = usr1.user_id
  LEFT JOIN user usr2 ON prod.buyer_id = usr2.user_id
WHERE condition on dates and PROD.STATUS_CODE IN (<<4 inputs>>)
```

Once i get the data am looping through each record and getting the values for the query and setting in same object

```
SELECT status_code,
       COUNT(*)
  FROM items
 WHERE returned = 1
   AND product_id =?
-- Cheking the status (which are different from prod status)

SELECT STK.STATUS_CODE, count( itm.*)
  FROM items itm
  JOIN stk stk ON stk.item_id = itm.item_id
 WHERE itm.product_id =?
```

Problem is if the first query returns too many records based on the date range, I need to iterate/loop through those many times and 2X times to fetch the DB records for the last 2 queries. Can anyone suggest/guide me give some pointers how can i minimize the round trip to DB, to fetch the data in a single go.

I try to use **[WITH clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause)** and partition over **dense_rank()** on product_id but i failed because it is giving too many records than original.

FYI: Am using oracle 12C

Any pointers will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: If only there was a fully-featured in-database programming language we could use for this type of task and avoid multiple round trips ;)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - I'm sure that counts as [snarkasm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311737/133829)

Comment: OK, being more constructive: you could reduce the number of round trips by coding the logic in a PL/SQL procedure. This could either do the whole job including getting the product list, or else be something you called once per product to handle both item count tasks in one shot.

Comment: Please give an [MCVE] including: DDL statements for your tables; DML statements for example data that is representative of your problem; an English (not code) description of how the data should be processed; and the expected output of the sample data going through your process. It may be possible to solve it in a single query or else to write a PL/SQL procedure to perform all the steps in the database but without a lot more information it is very difficult to try to determine what you are doing.

Comment: @MT0 Where can i upload my DDL's , is there any site, please let me know so that i can prepare and upload them. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Do you only run the third query if the second query returns results?

Comment: @Boneist No last 2 queries are executed independently (they are not dependent on each other)

Comment: @mallikarjun Re. adding your DDL, sample data and expected output, you can edit your question to add the information in there.

Comment: @mallikarjun If you have answered your own question then it should go into an answer (it is allowed to answer your own questions) not an edit to your question. You should move your edit to an answer than the rollback the question to the original version. Alternatively, if your question is not going to be valuable to anyone other than you you can opt to delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks every one i finally got the answer for it.
Here is the process i followed, sorry i don't have access to the entire schema will post the DDL in a while.

Here is the query i finally wrote to meet my requirements.

```
    WITH 

PROD_RPT AS (
    SELECT prod.product_id as prodId,
       prod.product_name,
       product.stock,
       st.status_code,
       st.status_desc,
       usr1.user_nameas AS soldby,
       usr2.user_nameas soldto,
       itm.status_code as itmStatus,
       itm. returned as returned,
       stk.status_code as stkStatus
  FROM product prod
  JOIN items itm ON prod.product_id = itm.product_id
  LEFT JOIN stk stk ON st.item_id = itm.item_id
  JOIN status ON prod.status_code = st.status_code
  LEFT JOIN user usr1 ON prod.agent_id = usr1.user_id
  LEFT JOIN user usr2 ON prod.buyer_id = usr2.user_id
  WHERE condition on dates and PROD.STATUS_CODE IN (<<4 inputs>>)
),

ITM_RPT AS (
  SELECT * FROM (
    select count(*) Over(partition by rpt.prodId, rpt.itmStatus ORDER BY rpt.prodId, rpt.itmStatus) cnt,
    row_number() Over(partition by rpt.prodId, rpt.itmStatus ORDER BY rpt.prodId, rpt.itmStatus) rn,
    rpt.*
    FROM PROD_RPT rpt WHERE rpt.returned = 1
  ) where rn = 1
),
ITM_STK_RPT AS (
  SELECT * FROM (
    select count(*) Over(partition by rpt.prodId, rpt.stkStatus ORDER BY rpt.prodId, rpt.stkStatus) cnt,
    row_number() Over(partition by rpt.prodId, rpt.stkStatus ORDER BY rpt.prodId, rpt.stkStatus) rn,
    rpt.*
    FROM PROD_RPT rpt
  ) where rn = 1
)

SELECT * FROM ITM_RPT
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM ITM_STK_RPT
```